# The poster fixes its own question code with the answers received

Tags: discussion

This is the [question in context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980081/binding-parameters-to-stored-procedure/27980714#27980714).

If you look at the original text of the question you could see that the initial problem was different. I was looking for the problem and get suspicious about the usage of a wrong enum value and posted a comment about it. Then I went to test my suspects (building a simple example with LinqPad) before posting an answer. In the meantime the poster fixed its question with the info provided in my comment thus changing the wrong code with a correct one, but then started to complain about another error. Another user provided an answer for the new problem and the poster fixed again its code with the new answer.

My question is: what we need to do here? Rolling back the question to its original text seems to be inappropriate (the new question has been accepted now). However my answer now is meaningless in the context of the question code. Should I delete my answer? or simply go to the next question?

Comment: OP certainly didn't adhere to the [question editing code standards](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/1820286) that shifted the question focus and raised yet another question possibly unrelated to the previous one. Exxaggerating, I'd say that in extreme cases it could turn into gradually-solve-all-my-code-issues war that should somehow be addressed. One plausible action is to rollback and ask OP to ask another question on the second issue he faced and this seems the most appropriate one. But how can we *enforce* it - that's definitely worth collecting opinions about.

Comment: Well, we could add a new flag for moderators attention: [Chamaleon question detected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). OK, OK just kidding :-). Please mods don't kill me.

Comment: fair enough - i posted the question and i didn't do very well here. apologies.